# how to make bookmarks in mw work to be acces by vb6?

Tags: vb6, ms-word, bookmarks

'Im doing some research on adding some text in a .doc file via vb6 language. But the code I found says'

```
With objWord.Bookmarks
  .Item("NAME").Range.Text = txtName
  .Item("ADDRESS").Range.Text = txtAddress
  .Item("CODE").Range.Text = txtCode
  .Item("PHONE").Range.Text = txtPhone
  .Item("FAX").Range.Text = txtFax
End With
```

the NAME,ADDRESS,CODE,PHONE,FAX are the bookmarks.

hos could i add bookmarks in msWord application?

thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Word may make a difference, but in Word 2003 you click **Insert|Bookmark** and in the dialog window that pops up you name your bookmark. Not to be snarky about it, but you could also try opening Word and pressing **F1**.